# Retrieving pageid from Wikipedia parse request

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm retrieving article content from the Wikipedia api using the `parse` module:

"http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=[...]&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

What I get back is an object with (amongst other properties) the html content of the requested page on it. What I would also like to have is the pageid of the requested page. Unfortunately this is not included and I can't find a way to get it as well other than making a second request using the `query` module.

Is it possible to get the pageid when requesting an article using the parse module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the pageid when requesting an article using the parse module?

I don't think so. Usually you know the id/title identifier of the page you are interested in. You will however get back the id of the revision that is parsed.

> What I get back is an object with the html content of the requested page on it.

If that's the only thing you're interested in, just use the query api! The [`revision` module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties#revisions_.2F_rv) will get you the parsed content as well:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvparse=1&titles=[…]&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK
```

Comment: I see! Yeah, `action=query&rvparse=1&rvprop=content` seems to work as well. Takes ages to parse though... but thanks a lot for the hint!